# Substitution error in bash

Tags: bash, associative-array, substitution

Here is the code:

```
declare -A data84
data84=( [Tom]=23 [Lucy]=32 )

function test()
{
    data=$1
    echo ${${data}[Tom]} #error 1: "${${data}[Tom]}" bad substitution

    a=${data}[Tom]
    echo ${a} #output unwanted result data84[Tom]
}
test data84
```

I wanted this function to be able to give `23` when calling `echo ${data84[Tom]}`. And also can you explain why I got the error 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@try:

```
declare -A data84
data84[Tom]=23
data84[Lucy]=32

function test()
{
    data=$1
    echo $data[Tom]

    a=$data[Tom]
    echo ${!a}
}
test data84
```

Output will be as follows

```
data84[Tom]
23
```

**Explanation:**

From man bash (parameter expansion):

> ```
>  ${parameter}
> ```
>
> The value of *`parameter`* is substituted.  The braces are required
>   when *`parameter`* is a positional parameter with more than one
>   digit, or when *`parameter`* is followed by a character which is not
>   to be interpreted as part of its name. [...]
>
> If the first character of *`parameter`* is an exclamation point (`!`),
>   a level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of *`parameter`* as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of *`parameter`*
>   itself. This is known as *indirect expansion*. The exceptions to this
>   are the expansions of `${!prefix*}` and
>   `${!name[@]}` described below. The exclamation point
>   must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce
>   indirection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Bash 4.3 or newer, this would be an excellent opportunity to use a [nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters). In doing so, you'll not only be able to access array elements without contortions, but also assign to them:

```
testfunc () {
    local -n data=$1
    echo "In testfunc: ${data[Tom]}"
    data[Lucy]=99
}

declare -A data84
data84=([Tom]=23 [Lucy]=32)

testfunc data84

echo "After testfunc:"
declare -p data84
```

This will print

```
In testfunc: 23
After testfunc:
declare -A data84='([Tom]="23" [Lucy]="99" )'
```

so we've actually changed `data84`.

Notice that `test` is a dangerous name for a function, as it might clash with the [`test`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test) shell builtin.

Comment: Can you explain what "local -n" does here? I did not find its explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @user6948979 It's in the manual: [Shell parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) (the last three paragraphs) and [The `declare` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) (under `-n`). It creates a reference to another variable. See also the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#nameref) and [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) and [BashFAQ/048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#The_problem_with_bash.27s_name_references)

Comment: `echo "In testfunc: ${data[Tom]}"` Why not `echo "In testfunc: ${${data}[Tom]}"`? When I do `echo ${data}`, it gives me nothing. Can you comment on that?

Comment: @user6948979 That's just the way you access an element in an associative array. `${data}`, for an array, defaults to `${data[0]}`, and since that is empty, you get the empty string. Once you have made `data` a nameref to `data84`, it behaves like it *were* `data84`.